# How much more complex is the "vector-based-data" solution than "tile-based-data" solution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, openstreetmap

I have downloaded the Routme project source for objective-c and played around with some tile data examples. For our application, we need to host all tile images on our custom server and provide them to our app. However, one tile image for iPhone is 10KB in size, making the whole tile pack for Europe or USA quite large. To reduce the required bandwidth, I started thinking about using the source OSM vector data. This would definitely lower the bandwidth requirement but then we would need to implement map rendering from vector data code ourselves. How much more complex is such a solution and are there any vector data rendering objective-c libs for openstreetmaps data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite a bit more complex, and while the requirements on bandwidth go down the according CPU and GPU requirements go up.
We've developed a framework for working with OpenStreetMap vector data that is available, however as a commercial product only.
If you are interested you can find more information through the web page:
http://www.fasterimaging.com/?page_id=26